# Where can I buy a digital version of Windows 7 for Boot Camp?

Tags: bootcamp, macbook-pro

I'm going to attempt to install Windows 7 via Bootcamp on my new Retina Macbook Pro.  Since it's lacking an optical drive, every tutorial / walkthrough that I find says I need an ISO version of Windows.  I can't seem to find any sort of direct download links / stores that don't seem shady though?  Where can I get a legit copy of windows in ISO format?

Comment: Generally the normal 'legit' method would be to buy a physical disk and create the iso yourself using something like hdutil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download it from here : http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/

You will need to have the product key to install it. If you don't have one you can buy it from Microsoft store.

Comment: I don't understand why this is downvoted.

Comment: Neither do I my friend :). Microsoft sells digital copy too.

Comment: @bruce I am interested in your solution if you can install with USB.